# Confusion in contour integration

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration

I am trying to find

$$I = \int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^\frac{1}{n}dx$$

using contour integration, where $n \ge 2$ is an integer.

My method is to define $f(z) = \left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^\frac{1}{n}$, which has branch points at $z = \pm 1$, so I include a branch cut on the real axis for $[-1,1]$. I then expand around $z = \infty$, which gives $f = 1 - \frac{2}{nz} + O(z^{-2}).$

Integrating this around a circle with radius $R >>1 $ gives $-4\pi i/n$. I then collapse the contour around the branch cut, and integrate essentially along the real axis, which should give $$-4 \pi i/n = i\int_{1}^{-1}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^\frac{1}{n}dx + i\int_{-1}^{1}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^\frac{1}{n} \cdot e^{i \pi}dx = - 2i\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^\frac{1}{n}dx$$

where the factor of $e^{i \pi}$ arises because we are below the branch cut.

So I have $I = 2 \pi / n$, but this cannot be right, because the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ should be $2$. I have only recently started teaching myself complex integration so maybe it is obvious but I cannot figure out where I have went wrong.

I have been able to show (albeit by integrating numerically and playing in desmos) that the answer appears to be $$ I = \frac{2^{3/2} \pi }{n\sqrt{1-cos\left(\frac{2 \pi}{n}\right)}},$$ however obviously I would like to see how one gets this using contour integration.

Comment: Along real axis, but what about $[-\infty,-1]$ and $[1,\infty]$ ? It is not a closed contour without those parts.

Comment: $z = \infty$ is not a branch point here? So I can choose $[-1,1]$ as a branch cut, I think

Comment: I have been able to show (albeit by integrating numerically and playing in desmos) that the answer appears to be $2^{3/2}/(n \cdot \sqrt{1-cos(2 \pi /n)})$, however obviously I would like to see how one gets this using contour integration.

Comment: There should be a factor of $\pi$ on the numerator above

Comment: ${\tt Mathematica}$ finds
$$
2 \text{Beta}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{n}+1,\frac{n-1}{n}\right)+\frac{2^{1/n}\ n \, \mbox{}_2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{n-1}{n};2-\frac{1}{n};\frac{1}{2}\right)}{n-1}\quad\to\ 2\quad {\rm as}\ n \to\ \infty
$$

Comment: You can click the edit button and make changes to the question.

Comment: @FelixMarin I should have mentioned this is only for positive integer n. Perhaps try evaluating the expression above and seeing if in the integer cases it is equivalent to the above integral.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it - there are two errors, both of which occur during the integration along the real axis. The first is the factor of $i$, which should be a factor or $(-1)^\frac{1}{n} = e^{-i \pi/n}$. The second is that the factor of $e^{i \pi}$ in the second integrand should be a factor of $e^{2 \pi i/n}$, reflecting the fact that we have the n$^{th}$ root, so we require to go over our branch cut $n$ times to get back to unity. This all changes the collapsing of the contour onto the real axis to:

$$\frac{-4\pi i}{n} = e^{-i \pi/n}\left[\int_1^{-1}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}  \right) ^{1/n}dx+\int_{-1}^{1}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}  \right) ^{1/n}\cdot e^{2 \pi i/n}  dx\right] = -2i \,\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{n} \right)I_n$$

$$\therefore I_n = \frac{2\pi}{n\, \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}\, ,$$
which gives the result at the bottom of the my question after some manipulation.